# Making a JQuery Dialog pop up box responsive

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, mobile, responsive-design

My school organization currently has a website that incorporates JQuery and uses "dialog" pop up boxes (JQuery-UI?). I am making the website responsive but do not know how to go about making the dialog boxes responsive. The only solution I have found is JQuery mobile but I am not sure how to implement it into our current website. I know my question is a little vague but I was wondering if anyone has a simple solution?

Here is what I believe to be the code for one of my pop-up boxes.  ( I don't understand code very well) Any and all help is appreciated.

```
$( "#dialog-new" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        width:900,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "Clear Form": function() {
      clearForm($("#newapsform"));

    },
            "Create Request": function() {

                if(formIsOkay($("#newapsform")))
                {
                    $.ajax
                    ({  
                      type: "POST",  
                      url: "system/aps2.newrequest.php",  
                      data: $("#newapsform").serialize(),  
                      success: function() 
                        {  
                            $( "#dialog-new" ).dialog( "close" );
                            $("#goodmsg").html("Created photo request successfully!");
                            $('#goodmsgdiv').fadeIn(1500).delay(3000).fadeOut(1500);

                            datatables.fnDraw();
                            searchtables.fnDraw();
                            phototables.fnDraw();
                            clearForm($("#newapsform"));
                        },
          error: function() 
                        {  
                            $( "#dialog-new" ).dialog( "close" );
                            $("#badmsg").html("Could not create request: Use the force next time.");
                            $('#badmsgdiv').fadeIn(1500).delay(3000).fadeOut(1500);
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: In general I don't think you should be making dialog boxes responsive. Dialogs should be small and concise. Hence they should fit on any screen anyway! If they are big then reconsider your design.

Comment: I don't know what is the best practice for this but IMHO dialog boxes should be implemented for smaller screens. I don't find it easy to deal with dialogs on my phone.

Comment: It's not my website.  A former employee designed it and at the time it was only used for desktops.  Now my manager wants it to be accessible from mobile devices.  So I have to make it responsive.  If i had the skills/time to redesign the entire thing, believe me I would.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the demo from this answer and it worked when i resize my laptop browser. haven't tried on mobile, though.

[Responsive jQuery UI Dialog ( and a fix for maxWidth bug )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471890/responsive-jquery-ui-dialog-and-a-fix-for-maxwidth-bug)

the demo here: http://codepen.io/jasonday/pen/amlqz

edit:
looks like it works with:
jquery-1.10.1.js
jquery-ui-1.9.2.js

```
$( "#dialog-new" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
        width: 'auto', // overcomes width:'auto' and maxWidth bug
        height: 300,
        maxWidth: 600,
        modal: true,
        fluid: true, //new option
        resizable: false,
        open: function(event, ui){ 
           fluidDialog(); // needed when autoOpen is set to true in this codepen
        },

        buttons: {
            "Clear Form": function() {
      ....
});

// run function on all dialog opens
$(document).on("dialogopen", ".ui-dialog", function (event, ui) {
    fluidDialog();
});

// remove window resize namespace
$(document).on("dialogclose", ".ui-dialog", function (event, ui) {
    $(window).off("resize.responsive");
});

function fluidDialog() {
    var $visible = $(".ui-dialog:visible");
    // each open dialog
    $visible.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var dialog = $this.find(".ui-dialog-content").data("dialog");
        // if fluid option == true
        if (dialog.options.maxWidth && dialog.options.width) {
            // fix maxWidth bug
            $this.css("max-width", dialog.options.maxWidth);
            //reposition dialog
            dialog.option("position", dialog.options.position);
        }

        if (dialog.options.fluid) {
            // namespace window resize
            $(window).on("resize.responsive", function () {
                var wWidth = $(window).width();
                // check window width against dialog width
                if (wWidth < dialog.options.maxWidth + 50) {
                    // keep dialog from filling entire screen
                    $this.css("width", "90%");

                }
              //reposition dialog
              dialog.option("position", dialog.options.position);
            });
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly post how to implement that into my current code.  I'm not a very strong coder.  :(