# Responsive popup in non-responsive page

Tags: html, css, width, meta-tags, responsiveness

There is a site. It is not responsive. For example, it has container/body width of 960 pixels.
There is popup window, which opens with some kind of Fancybox (in real life - remodal).
The window and the content in this window is responsive. But when it opens on mobile, popup window doesn't use CSS rules for current smartphone display width, because the site is static and has 960 pixels width.
How can I redefine meta viewport tag (or anything else), to make browser think that site is responsive and open responsive popup?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply @media queries directly to any element. It might not be so easy with a 3rd party modal but in theory its possible.

```
@media (min-width:468px){...}
@media (max-width:4768px){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use use responsive Jquery UI for the modal, Take a look here, if that helps:
[possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621440/making-a-jquery-dialog-pop-up-box-responsive)